# Jquery tablesorter plugin: trying to sort 2 index same time

Tags: jquery, indexing, row, grouping, tablesorter

i would like to know if it s possible to get sort for 2 index with tablesorter jquery's plugin.

My table is build as it:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th align="left" width="40%">Nom fichier</th>
        <th align="left">UO</th>
        <th align="left">Nb pages</th>
        <th align="left">D&eacute;lai&nbsp;</th>
        <th align="left">Etat</th>
        <th>Imprimer</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="sectiontableentry2">
        <td valign="top" align="left" class="">
            <a href="#r1544790" id="r1544790">DI.DISLOT06.060312.103648.TE.MR510</a>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">ImpRV - Autres impressions recto-verso</td>
        <td valign="top">1645.00</td>
        <td valign="top" class="alertred">15/03/2012</td>
        <td valign="top">Transfert Fichier vers PRISMA</td>
        <td>imprimer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none" id="1544790">
        <td colspan="6" width="100%">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  class="det_suivi" style="display:block;text-align:left;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><h4 style="text-align:left;">DI.DISLOT06.060312.103648.TE.MR510</h4></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Log</th>
                    <th>Date heure</th>
                    <th>Etat</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="sectiontableentry1">
                    <td align="left">1 - reception + demande uo</td>
                    <td align="left">06/03/2012 10:35:00</td>
                    <td align="left">Bon �  produire</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="sectiontableentry0">
                    <td align="left">2 - Transfert Fichier vers PRISMA</td>
                    <td align="left">06/03/2012 10:35:04</td>
                    <td align="left"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>



    <tr class="sectiontableentry2">
        <td valign="top" align="left" class="">
            <a href="#r1544790" id="r1544991">DI.DISLOT06.060312.103648.TE.MR769</a>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">ImpRV - Autres impressions recto-verso</td>
        <td valign="top">1645.00</td>
        <td valign="top" class="alertred">23/03/2012</td>
        <td valign="top">Transfert Fichier vers PRISMA</td>
        <td>imprimer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none" id="1544991">
        <td colspan="6" width="100%">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  class="det_suivi" style="display:block;text-align:left;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><h4 style="text-align:left;">DI.DISLOT06.060312.103648.TE.MR769</h4></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Log</th>
                    <th>Date heure</th>
                    <th>Etat</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="sectiontableentry1">
                    <td align="left">1 - reception + demande uo</td>
                    <td align="left">06/03/2012 10:35:00</td>
                    <td align="left">Bon �  produire</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="sectiontableentry0">
                    <td align="left">2 - Transfert Fichier vers PRISMA</td>
                    <td align="left">06/03/2012 10:35:04</td>
                    <td align="left"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="sectiontableentry2">
        <td valign="top" align="left" class="">
            <a href="#r1544790" id="r1544791">DI.DISLOT06.060312.103648.TE.MR999</a>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">ImpRV - Autres impressions recto-verso</td>
        <td valign="top">1645.00</td>
        <td valign="top" class="alertred">05/03/2012</td>
        <td valign="top">Transfert Fichier vers PRISMA</td>
        <td>imprimer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none" id="1544791">
        <td colspan="6" width="100%">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  class="det_suivi" style="display:block;text-align:left;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><h4 style="text-align:left;">DI.DISLOT06.060312.103648.TE.MR999</h4></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Log</th>
                    <th>Date heure</th>
                    <th>Etat</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="sectiontableentry1">
                    <td align="left">1 - reception + demande uo</td>
                    <td align="left">06/03/2012 10:35:00</td>
                    <td align="left">Bon �  produire</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="sectiontableentry0">
                    <td align="left">2 - Transfert Fichier vers PRISMA</td>
                    <td align="left">06/03/2012 10:35:04</td>
                    <td align="left"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I use the default configuration.

My problem is the

> style="display:none"

in the table: this is the detail view content of the row

1st inde: normal
2nd index: detail of the 1st one
3nd index: normal
4th index: detail of the 3nd 
...

Default sort on date for example will put the 1st, 3nd, 5th index together on top and the rest at bottom.

So i would like to try to sort by grouping the 1st with 2nd index ...

How could i do ?

ty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, I think you just need to add the child-row class name to the hidden table rows. Here is the [original demo](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm) which has a link to download it, but don't download it because it was merged into [tablesorter version 2.0.5](http://tablesorter.com/docs/), it just wasn't documented.

So, basically all you need to do is add the "expand-child" class to the hidden rows.

```
$('table').tablesorter({
  cssChildRow: "expand-child" // default setting
});
```

HTML

```
<tr class="expand-child" style="display:none" id="1544790">
...
</tr>
```

**NOTE*: It is not recommended to have an element ID that starts with a number, so instead of `id="1544790"` add any letter to the beginning: `id="n1544790"` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)).

Comment: is that i was looking for ... many thanks ;). Ty for the tip on ID, i will apply ;).